# weak consequence of GCH

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

Can ZFC prove that there is a regular uncountable cardinal $\kappa$ such that $2^{<\kappa} < 2^\kappa$?

Note, if the answer is no, it would require a strong global violation of SCH, so large cardinals to force this.

On the other hand, it may be true for an easy reason, but I haven't found one.  But I did figure it out under the assumption that there are no weak inaccessibles.

Comment: Note that if ZFC *does* prove this, then it must be a successor cardinal (since ZFC can't even prove that there *is* a regular limit uncountable cardinal!) which reduces the question to whether ZFC can prove that there exists some cardinal $\alpha$ with $2^\alpha\lt 2^{\left(\alpha^+\right)}$.

Comment: I think this fails. Starting with a model of GCH and no inaccessibles, do class Easton forcing to make $2^{\aleph_\alpha}=\aleph_{\alpha+\omega+1}$ for all regular $\aleph_\alpha$. The resulting model will have $2^\kappa=2^{\kappa^+}$ for all regular $\kappa$ and still have no inaccessibles (I think). So we should have $2^{<\kappa}=2^\kappa$ for all regular uncountable $\kappa$.

Comment: Sorry Miha, this is wrong.  GCH will still hold at singular $\kappa$, so we'd have there $2^\kappa=(\kappa^+)^{<\kappa^+} =\kappa^+<2^{\kappa^+}$.

Comment: I mean at singular strong limit, GCH will hold.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was pointed out to me by Emil on mathoverflow that my argument under the assumption "no weak inaccessibles" goes through without that assumption.  Here's the argument:

Assume towards a contradiction that that for all regular $\kappa$, $2^{<\kappa} = 2^\kappa$.  Denote $\mathfrak{c} =  2^\omega$.  We will arrive at a contradiction by showing that $2^\alpha = \mathfrak{c}$ for all $\alpha$, by induction.

Suppose this holds for all $\beta < \alpha$, and $\alpha$ is regular.  By hypothesis, $2^\alpha = 2^{<\alpha} = \mathfrak{c}$.  Now suppose $\alpha$ is singular.  We have a general formula $2^\alpha = (2^{<\alpha})^{cf(\alpha)}$ (see Jech Chapter 5).  In this case we have $2^\alpha = \mathfrak{c}^{cf(\alpha)} = (2^\beta)^{cf(\alpha)} = 2^\beta = \mathfrak{c}$ for some $\beta < \alpha$.

By the way, this generalizes to show that for every $\alpha$, there is a regular $\kappa \geq \alpha$ such that $2^\kappa > 2^{<\kappa}$.

Comment: Nice! I guess your argument also shows that there is such a cardinal of size at most continuum (which is best possible in ZFC).